# What is the 95% confidence interval / ellipse in a PCA plot telling me?

Tags: confidence-interval, pca

I am new to statistics and within the last two days I tried to get my head around PCA plots. Now, I kind of understand what they are showing but I am still not sure about the 95% confidence ellipse that is very often shown in such plots. The 2 dimensional PCA plot displays the two biggest variances (whatever these are) in the data but I don't know what the ellipse is trying to tell me and what it means if a sample/dot (whatever is displayed) is lying outside that ellipse.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your signature is automatically added so I deleted the one you typed.

Comment: You can view it as a particular contour of the closest bivariate normal distribution. With 95% confidence, the true center is located within this curve.

Answer (score 1):

The ellipse around a scatter plot of "component 1" vs. "component 2" has a similar meaning to the ellipse around any other scatter plot. Unfortunately, there are two common uses of such ellipses: Prediction ellipses and confidence ellipses. [`SAS` documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63963/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_corr_sect021.htm) explains the difference (as do other sites)

Comment: Hi Peter. thanks for your answer. I tried to follow and understand the explanation in the SAS documentation but I don't really. I still cannot tell the meaning of the 95% ellipse and as well not sure about the difference of a prediction and confidence ellipse. Isn't the ellipse in a PCA plot not always a confidence ellipse??